# Is there any algorithm to determine if two λ-terms are equal?

Tags: functional-programming, lambda-calculus

Given two lambda terms, let's say they are equal if their (possibly infinite) Bohm trees are. Under this definition, for example, `(Y λr.λt.(t r))` and `(Y λr.λt.t (λt. t r)` are equal, despite not having a normal form, because both terms have the same infinite Bohm trees. Since this reduces to the halting problem, the best we can have is a probabilistic function. My question is: is there any efficient, preferably simple algorithm capable of determining if two λ-terms are equal for some large class of common terms?

Comment: Good luck! (Why tag this Haskell?)

Comment: One might say that the terms with normal forms are a large class of common terms.  You might be able to use well quasi-order (WQO) techniques to check for divergence so that you will always halt.  Just curiosity, or are you trying to solve a particular problem (which might guide the best answer)?

Comment: @luqui I'm just experimenting with implementing a type system that allows recursive definitions, thus conversion checking requires it to be capable of telling that as many as possible cases of those infinite terms are equal.

Comment: I suspect that in general this is not decidable, though I couldn't provide a proof.

Comment: Equality on regular Böhm trees is decidable.

Comment: @augustss that's surprising to me, but sorry for making an incorrect assumption. Would love a reference / explanation! But I struggle to see how such procedure could, for example, decide that `(Y λr.λa.b.(a λa.b.(b r)))` and `λa.λb. (a (Y λr.λa.λb.(b λa.λb.(a r)))` are equal (they both expand to the equivalent of the Church-encoded bit-string "01010101...", thus have the same Bohm trees, but are implemented with two mis-aligned tying-the-knot terms, thus, just unrolling definitions won't ever arrive to identical terms).

Comment: I've voted to close as off-topic. I find this an interesting question, but if anything, it's one for [CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) or [CStheory.SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @leftaroundabout perhaps but why do we have a tag for the λ-calculus if we're not supposed to ask questions about it?

Comment: I used “regular” in a technical sense.  It might not be what you expect.  http://pauillac.inria.fr/~huet/PUBLIC/RBT2.pdf